# How to make full screen caller id in android?

Tags: android, contacts, phone-call

I Want to develop Full Screen caller application with Caller details and accept call and ignore button how to achieve this? .I searched a lot but i'm not able to find solution or any reference, so anyone can lead or help me or any reference it would be helpful for me, thanks in advance happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to give you ready-made code even though I could probably dig into my own and do it. You said you *searched a lot* but if this were true, you'd have found many references to articles and docs such as these.

- [Get contact data from number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079365/android-retrieve-contact-name-from-phone-number)
- [Take control of calls programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012082/rejecting-incoming-call-in-android)
- [Detect incoming calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device)
- [Interesting considerations for incoming calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338526/activity-popups-over-incoming-call-screen)

That should get you started. But it should go someting like this: Register that you want to be notified when incoming calls are received. On that notification you receive launch your own activity that takes control of the calls programmatically (button to dismiss, button to accept?). That screen can show whatever you want, beit the contact information you retrieved from the phone number, a photo, etc.